# Backbone sync error even after response code 200

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-mvc, backbone.js

Hello Backbone ninjas,

This is my first time using Backbone - so please excuse my "noob"ness. 
In my functionality (part of a larger app),I have a Backbone View vA, backed by a model mA (as it should be ) and the server side is in Spring MVC having annotated Spring controller methods with @RequestBody and @ResponseBody. I've got Jackson working fine with Spring.

Now, in the app,

```
Backbone.Model
 |_ BaseModel (custom base model for our app)
   |_ mA (my model)
```

mA has its own endpoint and it Backbone sucessfully calls that when making a PUT request i.e., when I call save() from a submit button event handler from View vA like so:

this.model.save({

```
            success : function(){

                    alert('Request submitted successfully');


            },

            error : function(){
                alert('Something awful happened.');
            }
```

});

Our BaseModel has the following:

```
define([], function() {



window.BaseModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
 ......


});

onSyncError : function(model, response) {
        switch (response.status) {
        case 403:
        [...//some more code ]
        default:
            alert(bundle.getDefault('HTTP_RESP_OTH') + response.status);
        }
    },

    onSyncSuccess : function(model, response) {
        alert('Sync done! ');
    },

    sync : function(method, model, options) {
        options.error = this.onSyncError;
        Backbone.sync.call(this, method, model, options);
        ....//some more stuff.      
    },

}
```

Spring controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/resource/xyz/{id}.json", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes     = {"application/json"}
, produces = {"application/json"})
@ResponseBody
public Map<String,String> methodX(@RequestBody XyzDTO  xyzDTO){
....
map.put("msg", "success");

return map;
}
```

Also, right before I make the save call, I modify a few Model attributes, since the server side DTO has a different structure like so:

```
this.model.unset("abc",{ silent: true });
this.model.set( { abc: {id : "2",xyz:{ ... //more code } );
```

The issue is, calling save() generates a PUT request and successfully calls the Spring endpoint handler, but I get a response code 200 (which is what I expect),
but when I trace the call with Firebug, it goes into the onSyncError method and gives me an error message (because of the "default" case in it).

The Backbone doc says : "When returning a JSON response, send down the attributes of the model that have been changed by the server, and need to be updated on the client". Well, I don't need to update the model on the client side, its one of the last screens and I just need to tell the user of a success / error and 
redirect him to a main page/dashboard.

I read up some more, and it seems code 200 as response is not sufficient - there might be JSON parsing errors causing the sync to fail.

I checked the response in Firebug, and the response JSON looks like {"msg":"Success"}.

So, what could be going wrong?

Comment: I am not sure if this would cause your issue, but I have had trouble before with the fact that `Backbone.Model.save()` actually requires you to put your save data as the first argument, like so: `model.save(model.toJSON(),{success:function(){},error:function(){});

I have run into issues with this in the past where I got weird errors just because I forgot that you must explicitly pass in the data you wish to save/post.  Might give this a try.

Comment: Thanks for your time. But it didn't help. Now, I get this in Firebug when the response returns: TypeError: a is undefined


    ... function bi(a, b, d) { var e = b.dir, f = d && b.dir === "parentNode", g = u++;...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your time. I was finally able to get around the problem by using $.ajax to make the PUT request, thereby bypassing the whole Backbone sync thingy. My success handler in the ajax callback handles the response and there are no more sync errors (since its not being called anyways) :)

Comment: No problem.  I'm not sure that skirting the issue by directly calling $.ajax is the best solution, but whatever works for you.  You also might check out [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394108/how-should-server-respond-to-backbone-sync?rq=1) which answers the question of how Server should respond to `model.save()`.

Answer (score 9):

`Backbone.Model.save()` expects the response from the server to be an updated hash of the model's values.  If your response is of the kind `{"msg":"Success"}`, Backbone may fail to sync with your model.  Basically, it interprets your HTTP 200 JSON response as the model's attributes and tries to sync the model accordingly.

You might try either 1) Making your Spring controller path return a JSON-ified model response,  2) Return a plain 200 with an empty response body or 3) write a custom [parse](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-66) method which looks for responses with the `{"msg":"Success"}` format and responds differently.

Comment: an empty response body will still call the error handler, a response of `'{}'` will not though

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my experience with the same problem; 
custom base-model and
calling model.save and no success event fired.

My problem was with a custom set function in the base model which didnt return "this".

If you peek at the backbone source code for model-save you'll find this snippet:

```
  options.success = function(resp) {
    // Ensure attributes are restored during synchronous saves.
    model.attributes = attributes;
    var serverAttrs = model.parse(resp, options);
    if (options.wait) serverAttrs = _.extend(attrs || {}, serverAttrs);
    if (_.isObject(serverAttrs) && !model.set(serverAttrs, options)) {
      return false;
    }
    if (success) success(model, resp, options);

    model.trigger('sync', model, resp, options);
  };
```

The !model.set(serverAttrs, options) failed in my case and the save-function returned false before triggering any events.

Maybe this wasn't your problem but hopefully it'll help someone else out there...

Answer (score 0):

Validate your JSON response..
In my case I had an extra comma (,)..
Nearly in-valid response may cause this issues