# backbone save fires error when response is 200

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

so nothing special uphere (which really is bugging me) .
im quite sure there is something that im missing .

so here is the bit of code that is relative  :

```
    _me.attributes.answers.push(oAnswer);
    _me.save(null,{
        success : function(){
            console.log('saved the answer');
            q = new q.Questions() ;
            q.fetch({
                success : function(data){
                    console.log('reloading the template with this data');
                    console.log(data)
                    this.render({model:data , el:this.$el})
                }
            })
        },
        error : function(model , response , x){
            console.log('error')
            console.log(response)
            console.log(x)
        }
    });
```

now i can see in my console that the request has been made `(PUT)` and that the server response is `200 (OK)` .

but i still get the `error` logged ,  when i tried to log the response i got this

```
readyState
    4

responseText
    "OK"

status
    200

statusText
    "OK"
```

still backbone just fires the `error` handler for the `_me.save` , why is that ?

Comment: so you're getting the error not on `_me.save` but on `q.fetch`?

Comment: Are you returning an empty body from your server? That's an [invalid response for jQuery](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-ajax-returning-a-json-result-of-an-empty-string). The other possibility is: if you doing a call from different domain, your browser is probably trying to do [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) for you.

Comment: @glortho yes im getting the error on the _me.save ,  it's the only error handler .

Comment: @j03w , actually im using nodejs express and im sending a response as follows `res.send(200)` .

Comment: @HusseinNazzal So it sounds like you need to change this: "still backbone just fires the error handler for the q.fetch , why is that ?"

Comment: @glortho i have edited the question , sorry about that .

Comment: @HusseinNazzal and does it has a respond body? Try sending along an empty JSON object with your `200`.

Comment: @j03w that worked thanks . if you like post it as an answer so i can accept it :)

Comment: I don't feel it's a dupe, because your framing of the question is unique, but this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394108/how-should-server-respond-to-backbone-sync

Answer (score 2):

Your server response isn't valid according to the parse function. Try passing "parse: false" to your model options when saving

```
model.save(attrs, {
  success: function() { ... },
  parse  : false
});
```

Comment: this problem has been resolved long ago .  thanks for taking time to share what you know . hope some one would benefit form it . :)